# Render main form and embedded form(s) individually?

Tags: symfony

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

[Symfony2 embedded forms rendering in a twig template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25821213/symfony2-embedded-forms-rendering-in-a-twig-template)

I am aware of how I might render the two forms on an individual field basis - but what I want to render the main form and sub-form in more expedient way:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
{{ form_widget(form.base) }}
{{ form_widget(form.child1) }}
{{ form_widget(form.child2) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Possible? Or do I have to render each of the fields individually if I need this type of control?

EDIT | HERE IS WHAT I HAVE

```
<div class="box box-primary">
                    {{ form_start(form) }}

                    <div class="nav-tabs-custom">
                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                          <li class="active"><a href="#activity" data-toggle="tab">Master</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#timeline" data-toggle="tab">Stock</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="tab-content">
                          <div class="active tab-pane" id="activity">
                            {{ form_row(form.partNumber) }}
                            {{ form_row(form.partDescription) }}
                          </div>

                          <div class="tab-pane" id="timeline">
                            {% for stock in form.inventoryStock %}
                                <div>{{ form_widget(stock.onHandQuantity) }}</div>
                                <div>{{ form_widget(stock.batchNumber) }}</div>
                                <div>{{ form_widget(stock.serialNumber) }}</div>
                            {% endfor %}
                          </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>                    

                    {{ form_end(form) }}
                </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should just need to do this:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

See the [Rendering the Form](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/forms.html#rendering-the-form) section of the Symfony documentation.  As long as everything is defined properly, Symfony will render all of the parts of the form for you, included forms that are embedded.

You often will need to use the capabilities for extra granularity but it's not required.

Also, it's absolutely possible to do what you stated - just give it a try and you'll see that you can.

Comment: That is how I have it now - the problem I am running into is wanting to render the main form in one tab and the embedded forms in another tab - thus requiring a bit of HTML tweaking - but I don't want to manually render each field as the entity may change or the fields visible may change. During this  volatile state would be nice to have symfony render forms independent. Not sure how???

Comment: Can't you just render the widget of each child on each tab?  tab1 - `{{ form_widget(form.child1) }}`, tab2...and so on.  I guess I don't understand what you're looking for then.

Comment: Not sure...the first example you gave renders the whole form...sub forms as well. I need the sun form rendered in a different tab. So I rendered those fields individually in the second tab. But they still partially render in the main as well.  Maybe I'll post my template tomorrow when at work...

Comment: Yeah seeing your template would help because you can definitely render just the sub form without doing each field individually

Comment: I'm a bit confused - it looks like `stock` is a completely separate form, not something that is embedded.

Comment: oh woops i missed the `for` loop.  couldn't you just do                           `<div class="tab-pane" id="timeline">{{ form_row(form.inventoryStock) }}</div>`?

Comment: Maybe but I don't want the stock lines render in one fell swoop - rather I want to render those three fields manually but the header details in one go???

Comment: What header details exactly?  It's still really confusing figuring out what you're trying to do or why you don't want to manually specify the fields.

Comment: The main form...has about 15 fields - some of which are not going to be shown because they are used internally (ie: times, etc) but for now I don't want to fuss over those details so I would rather render the parent form in its entirety. The sub-form...or collection of forms have only 3-4 fields and I need to figure out how I am going to render those so I would like to manually render each row